# Watch video and share on social media for rewards is allowed by google policy?

Tags: video, watch, policy, reward

I making a 'Watch Video for reward' option for users. Also I would like to add another option where the users will redirected to my Facebook fan page to like it for rewards. These are allowed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to reward people for liking/sharing your Facebook page, but it is not allowed to open the page without a confirm by the user.

Comment: Thank you, I will confirm the user. Whats about the watching videos?

Comment: People are allowed to watch video's on your site, why wouldn't they?

Comment: I'm not sure is legal, if I give rewards for it.

Comment: I checked the google sites policy, and they do not state anything about rewards for watching video's to be illegal.